Написание комментариев под постом aiogram ботом
Делаю бота на aiogram 3.15, пишущего комментарий под новый пост в канале, но не понимаю, как проверять, является ли сообщение в чате-обсуждении постом из привязанного канала.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь
